# Inverse Incidence Rate Ratio

Tags: stata, incidence-rate-ratio

I wondered if it is possible to calculate the inverse of an IRR like we can for odds ratio (inverse = 1/x).

For example:

IRR = 1.40, 95% CI = 1.18 -1.65

Inverse IRR:
= 1/1.40 = 0.71

Thank you
(Using Stata 11)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that just gives you the rate ratio with 1 as the referent group instead of 0 (for a binary variable) or for a one unit decrease in the variable (for a continuous variable) exactly as with a risk ratio or odds ratio.